# Alter Indexes mysql table for optimizing WordPress

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I am using WordPress with MySQL and the query takes too long to respond.

https://i.ibb.co/Pzwv1Hk/image.png

I am trying to add indexes using this query

```
ALTER TABLE lfab_posts ADD INDEX latest_post_date ('post_status', 'post_date' DESC)
```

what is wrong in the syntax? This **lfab_posts** table already has indexes as shown in the attached picture.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/frNse.png

Comment: What happens when you try to add the index?

Comment: https://ibb.co/wyddD1B

Comment: Don't quote your column names. That passes the values as strings instead of identifiers. If you need to use some sort of quote, it should be ticks, not single quotes

Comment: why u closed the question? It is not the answer to my question

Comment: Did you try removing the quotes? Both a validation error checker and the error message itself say that the error starts at `'post_status'`, because the columns should not be surrounded by single quotes. They are column names, not values, so should be surrounded by ticks or not at all.

Comment: https://ibb.co/VTZdzhz
it is the same. there is a syntax error in it. That's what I am asking

Comment: I have visited this link but unable to figure out the mistake. How to sort it by DESC order?
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/descending-indexes.html
Mysql version
https://ibb.co/FspWvHM

Comment: Okay, there's actually two different issues at play here, with the quotations fixed. The first is the PhpMyAdmin validator, which doesn't like the syntax but it seems to go ahead and submit the query. The second is the error that MySQL is throwing, which is that it doesn't like the default value for `post_date`. So it's no longer a syntax error, but a data error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218304/discussion-between-wedevelop-and-aynber).